# Cplex - The first station to visit has to be one that doesn´t fulfill lower and upper criteria

Tags: cplex

Good evening,

I´m currently working on Cplex and if someone could help me figure out a simple doubt in my Cplex program would be great.

My program aims to optimize the number of bicycles at each station in a small network of a bike sharing system.
With a discrepant use of bikes between stations, it is sometimes necessary to rebalance the number of bikes in certain stations and guarantee that each station has a number of bikes between a predefined interval.

My goal is to assure that the first stop of the truck in charge of bike rebalancing is in one station that has either a shortage (lower than L) or a surplus (higher the U) of bikes.

Here is my code. Any help would be great, thank you in advance :)

```
forall (i in stations)
        if (e[i]>U[i]) {
          sSurplus [i] == 1;
        } else {
          sSurplus[i] == 0;
        }
        
forall (i in stations)
        if (e[i]<L[i]) {
          sShortage [i] == 1;
        } else {
          sShortage[i] == 0; 

sum (i in stations)
     firstStation [i] == 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose sSurplus  is a decision variable then instead of

```
forall (i in stations)
        if (e[i]>U[i]) {
          sSurplus [i] == 1;
        } else {
          sSurplus[i] == 0;
        }
```

you should rather writer

```
forall (i in stations) sSurplus [i]==(e[i]>=U[i]+1);
```

Comment: Thank you. Suppose firstStation is a decision variable. If I want that station to be either the sSurplus or sShortage, how should I do it? `sum (i in stations) firstStation [i] == 1;` @Alex Fleischer

Comment: forall (i in stations) firstStation [i]<=maxl(sSurplus[i],sShortage[i]);